# Getting the Erlang shell to forget a BIF

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell, erl

Is there any way I can get Erlang to forget a built in function so I can use that name?

eg. forget retrieve

Answer (score 6):

There's a bit of confusion here.

1. `retrieve` is not a built-in function, you may be thinking of `receive`
2. `receive` is not a built-in function, but a special token in the language, much like `if`, `case`, `end`, and so on. These cannot be modified.
3. BIFs are mostly implemented in the `erlang` module, and you cannot redefine this one
4. Many of the BIFs in `erlang` are *auto-imported* in modules and such. Any module-local definition will take over these, and otherwise they're syntactic shortcuts for `erlang:MyBif(...)`.
5. The shell replicates these auto-imports, but also provides additional functions. They are technically not BIFs. See [Shell Commands](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html)
6. You can override the auto-imports for the shell by configuring your own [`user_default`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/shell_default.html) module. These will only work in the shell.
7. To avoid auto-imports in modules, use the `-compile({no_auto_import,[Name/N]}).` module attribute, so that `Name(...)` always uses the local function.